# How to extract sftp url sftp://<user>@<host>[:<port>][/<directory>] in java

Tags: java

Below is the S FTP config in properties file where its contains all attribute in a single line.

Properties file:

```
xyz.sftp=sftp://user@india123.systems.in:9090/<directory>
```

Example:

```
sftp://<user>@<host>[:<port>][/<directory>]
```

I want to parse it and get the following values out of this URL:

1. user
2. host
3. port
4. path

Comment: You should look at regex in Java, I have a hunch that is what will help you.

Comment: Could you please help me with regex example , as i am new to it.for the same

Comment: No, I can't. If you are not willing to learn new stuff on your own and depend on others to do everything for you, you are not a good fit to become a programmer. I pointed you in correct direction, it is up to you what you do with my advice.

Comment: go to https://regex101.com/ (or similar regex helper site) and drop in your text and start learning some regex. Let me get you started `sftp\:\/\/(.*)@` would capture the username part in group 1.

Comment: Thanks alot, I will go through regex link you provided , and will try to follow your tips.

Comment: Finally got :-) 
sftp\:\/\/(.*)@(.*):([\d]+)(.*) is helping me to extract all attributes

Answer (score 4):

You can use `java.net.URI` to parse URLs:

```
String ss = "sftp://user@india123.systems.in:9090/some/path";

URI uri = new URI(ss);
System.out.printf("URI scheme '%s' user '%s' host '%s' port '%s' path '%s'\n",
        uri.getScheme(), uri.getUserInfo(), uri.getHost(),
        uri.getPort(), uri.getPath());
```

Prints:

> URI scheme 'sftp' user 'user' host 'india123.systems.in' port '9090' path '/some/path'

The `java.net.URL` class has similar parsing abilities, but it'll throw an exception in this case because it doesn't recognize the "sftp" scheme. To avoid that, you'd have to register a protocol handler for the scheme. Registering protocol handlers is apparently rather painful to do; [this page](http://mjremijan.blogspot.com/2012/02/create-your-own-java-url-handlers.html) describes one way to do it.

Comment: is there any way to make it recognize sftp schema. ?

Comment: is there any issue if we use like this: 
ss = ss.replace("sftp", "ftp");
URI uri = new URI(ss);